# Fragment is added to activity and fragments oncreateview is called but view is not being inflated?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which extends appcompatactivity and i'm adding a fragment in framelayout inside this activity.The fragments oncreateview is being called but fragments view is not being inflated or shown.

AppCompat activity's layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:background="#fff" >    

    <FrameLayout    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contain">    
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm adding fragment to the child framelayout.The code to attach fragment is below:

```
OneFragment m = new OneFragment();   
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.contain,m);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

This is the code inside oncreateview of OneFragment:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        //Find the +1 button
        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

        return view;
```

Fragment_one.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OneFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        plus:size="standard"
        plus:annotation="inline" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? error in runtime?

Comment: No i'm not getting any exceptions or errors.

Comment: what you getting a white blank page ?

Comment: yes i'm getting a blank page.View of that fragment is not shown

Comment: show us fragment_one.xml

Comment: please post xml of fragment_one

Comment: Seems ok. Lets try few things. Remove the parent FrameLayout from activity's layout file

Comment: I need that framelayout because there is an image button which should be placed at bottom right corner.

Comment: try setting text to your buttons. and then run your application. may be because you set their size to `wrap_content` and there is no content, your widgets are invisible.

Comment: i dont think that'll help.In preview its showing the button